# Functors - Are they used to make Operator Overloading more easy?

Tags: c++, stl

The below piece of code is very common to implement Min-Heap :

```
struct comparator
{
    bool operator() ( int i, int j)
    { return j < i; }
};

priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, comparator> minHeap;
```

How Functors work? 
What purpose they solve in C++?
I could see Functors are more often used to Overload comparison.
Are they just used to make Operator Overloading easy?

When to create Functors?
How to create our own functor?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think are more appropriate place to point them would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes probably the better dupe. Reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comparator` struct is an example of something usually called a 'functor' in C++. A functor is a 'callable object' - that is a regular object that implements `operator()`, the function call operator. When used like this in an STL container, you are passing the *type* of the functor rather than an *instance* of it as a template argument. The container will create instances as necessary in order to actually call `operator()` on them.

If you are familiar with lambdas in C++, they are really just syntactic sugar for functors. A lambda definition creates an anonymous type which you can think of as a compiler-generated functor type with an `operator()` corresponding to the lambda function.

Functors (or lambdas) are the standard way in C++ to pass functions to types or other functions. This is useful in many situations, the example allows you to customize the sorting criteria for the `priority_queue`. The STL uses functors all over the place in containers and the algorithms library as a way to parameterize types and functions on a user supplied function.

Answer (score 1):

`comparator` is functor type used internally to sort container.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

By default STL uses builtin comparator `std::less` that is doing `i < j`. In your example custom comparator is used to sort container in reversed order. Your example can be rewritten as:

```
priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater> minHeap;
```